# Assign new variables when using .SD to apply function on multiple variables in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I understand how to use .SD to perform an operation on multiple columns; I just don't know how to assign those new values to new variables in my data table (not overwriting the input variables)

In this example I create three new vars ending with the string "newvars".  I than merge those new vars back on to the data table.  Is it possible to just create the new vars without the merge?

```
mtcars <- data.table( mtcars )  
newvars <- mtcars[ , lapply( .SD , function( Z ) Z * mtcars[[  "wt" ]]) , .SDcols= c("hp","drat","gear")]   
colnames(   newvars ) <- paste( colnames( newvars) , "newvars", sep="_")
mtcars <- cbind( mtcars , newvars )
```

Seems like there should be a straight forward way of doing this.

If I didn't have so many columns I would just do them one by one

```
mtcars[ ,   hp_new := hp*wt ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: wait where do I assign "newvars" in this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you are adding new columns. The idiomatic way is to use `:=` as follows, by putting the new character vector of column names within brackets `()` before `:=`

```
library(data.table)
mtc <- data.table(mtcars)
cols <- c("hp", "drat", "gear")
mtc[, (paste0(cols, "_newvars")) := lapply(.SD, `*`, wt), .SDcols=cols]
mtc
```

In addition, you do not need to access `wt` column using `[[` within `j` (see `?data.table` for definition of `j`)

Comment: Thank you! and thank you for the tip on j